# office 365 SharePoint app deployment with VS 2013

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, office365-apps

I don't have SharePoint installed in my machine.
I have installed VS 2013 Ultimate and have Office 365 developer site. And I want to develop Sharepoint 2013 apps without SharePoint installed in my machine.
When I open VS I can select template as Sharepoint 2013 apps and give URL of the site and select the hosting option. After do some smart coding I build the solution and then deployed.
When I navigate to Office 365 developer site I couldn't find the deployed app.
What is the issue? Anything I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

First check output in Visual Studio to ensure that the app was indeed deployed successfully.
Second go to your Office 365 development site where it's supposed to be deployed. It should appear in "Recent" section in the side menu on left side. Alternatively go to Site Contents and your app should appear as a tile there.

If that still gives you trouble, try with a sample app project - open it and deploy it and see if that works.